# Transparent navbar for materializecss

Tags: html, css, materialize

I tried making my navbar transparent in materializecss but all attempts l made turned it into white. Any suggestions will help. Thanks. Here is my code attempt

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper transparent">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"></a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Second attempt l tried this

```
<nav class="transnav">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo"></a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

With the added CSS, that did't work either.

```
.transnav {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have another element which have a background color. The way to debug it would be to inspect all the elements in Inspect mode (eg: Google Chrome inspect) and look at the CSS of each children to potentially find one that has a white background, and override it.

I can you don't manage, you can do it the quick and dirty (very dirty) way.

Try

```
.transnav * {
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;
      }
```

It will tell all children of .transnav to have background-color transparent.

Comment: I tried what you said, it didn't work. It reset the navbar color to the default color.

Comment: Try using the 'Inspect' mode in Chrome to find out where the culprit is, or share a link of your webpage I'll give it a look

Answer (score 0):

just give `.nav{background:none;}` property to you nav,and if there is anymore elements with the white background give `.element{background:none;}` to all elements you want with transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

> You Should try bellow example. It will work for you. You have missed
>   to set `!important` on css

```css
nav{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.nav-wrapper a{
  color: #aaa !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)!important;">
```